# Get name of last called method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, methods

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        try
        {
            this.CheckValue(true); // call method
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // how to get here name of last called method
        }
    }

    public int CheckValue(bool sender)
    {
        var qwe = int.Parse("qwe"); // invoke an exception

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I need to get in "catch block" name of last called method (in this case "CheckValue"), but it return that called method is "StringToNumber".

I try to get it using StackTrace:

```
stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name; -> "Main"
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(); -> "Void .ctor()"
ex.TargetSite.Name; -> "StringToNumber"
```

It's possible to do this?

Comment: To attract more answers, you should add a tag corresponding to the language or tools you are using. You can do that by [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11794081/edit) and adding tags at the bottom of the edit page.

Comment: Can you also please give us background on *why* you are trying to do so? By giving us context, we may also be able to suggest alternative solutions to your problem.

Comment: May I ask why `ex.StackTrace` isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer:

**Yes, You can!!!**

---

I'd just play around with Extension Methods and the trick here, is to get the last frame of the desired class, otherwise it would get methods of mscorlib assembly. So here it go:

```
public static string GetLastCalledMethod<T>(this Exception ex)
{
    var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex);
    var lastFrame = stackTrace.GetFrames().FirstOrDefault(frame => frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName == typeof(T).FullName);

    string methodName = string.Empty;
    if (lastFrame != null)
        methodName = lastFrame.GetMethod().Name;

    return methodName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:

### You can't.

---

Long Answer:

If you really need to do that, you will need to perform logging code in all the methods you want to track.

You can create a global variable (ugh) to store a `MethodInfo` with the last called method, and inside every method, set it to `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()`. Then whenever you want, you can examine that variable to see which method set it last.

---

In your case, you probably are trying to determine which method the exception was thrown in. You are looking at `TargetSite`, which returns the lowest method in the hierarchy, whereas you seem to want the one immediately below the current method. If simply examining `Exception.StackTrace` doesn't provide enough information, you might be able to parse out information from `StackTrace` and use reflection to get a `MethodInfo`. Usually, the `StackTrace` is good enough.

You may also be able to throw a new exception in the top-level method, so you can get the `TargetSite` from the new one.

Summary:

If `Exception.StackTrace` doesn't provide enough information, then you will either have to:

- Perform logging code in each method you want to check for.
- Parse out what information you can get from the `Exception`.
- Change the exception throwing scheme to throw a new exception with `InnerException` set to the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this.. because this is expected behaviour. The site of the exception is what you're being shown.. within the int.Parse() calls.

That being said.. if you really want to do this, you need to wrap a try.. catch in CheckValue, and re-throw the exception from there, but in a way that breaks the call stack.. like so:

```
public int CheckValue(bool sender) {
    try {
        var qwe = int.Parse("qwe"); // invoke an exception

        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex; // this breaks the call stack and re-throws the exception from here..
    }
}
```

Then, ex.TargetSite.Name == "CheckValue". I'm still not sure why you'd want to do this.. as a stack trace will actually show you where it all unwinds from after failure.

Comment: This is a small example, but in real situation I have a try/catch block with calling of about 80 methods(each method check something), so when some check method fail, I need to know method name that fail.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to maintain your own stack, rather than re-throwing exceptions in this way.