# How do I get the name of last inner method executed in a nested method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

How do I get the name of last inner method executed in a nested method?

Suppose I have a `Mainmethod()` it will call `Submethod1()` and `Submethod2()` then will come back to `Mainmethod()`.

I need the last executed `Submethod` name here `Submethod2()` is there any mechanism in C# ?
i am not looking for the Main method name.....last method which executed from the Mainmethod()
reflection?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question already got an answer.

[older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794081/get-name-of-last-called-method)

Is it what you were looking for ?

Comment: i need, if i am executing MyMethod from main and internally i am calling MyMethod2 from Mymethod1 then i should get last executed method.here name should be MyMethod2.Last executed method name from the Mainmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMethod();
    }

    public static void MyMethod([CallerMemberName] String caller = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(caller); // Outputs Main
    }
}
```

Comment: i need, if i am executing MyMethod from main and internally i am calling MyMethod2 from Mymethod1 then i should get last executed method.here name should be MyMethod2.Last executed method name from the Mainmethod.